# Access char sequence in arrays of char pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I have a problem with assigning specific pointer to another char sequence(string);

```
#include<stdio.h>
void setInformations(char *informations[], char *contests_name[]);
int main(void) {
   char *informations[]={"","","",""};
   char *contests_name[]={"cycle_race","swim","running race"};
   int totalTime=0;
   setInformations(informations,contests_name);
   getch();
   return 0;
}

void setInformations(char *informations[], char *contests_name[]) {
    printf("Competitor's name: ");
    scanf("%s",*informations[0]);
    printf("%s",informations[0]);
}
```

I know that the problem is assigning string to pointer of type char. How can I replace this (strcpy?)

Comment: first you need a buffer for your input.

Comment: I am unclear on what you're asking.  I can tell you've got a * where you don't need it in that scanf -- if it were *informations[0], you'd be reading in a char ("%c").  What part of the code is not working?

Comment: And Horvath's comment there meant that each entry in informations needs to have enough room to store the input -- "" doesn't have room to store anything.

Comment: @WillBriggs I want to know how I can put competitor's name in first element of *informations. I know that scanf is wrong now and I wanna now how I can do it differently. Thank you

Comment: vertical spacing in the code listing is a good thing, it makes the code ever so much easier to read.

Comment: regarding this line: 
 
this line: char *informations[]={"","","",""}; probably should be: char informations[4]; (no need to pre initialize the actual strings.) somewhere, later in the code, there needs to be a malloc for each string point, to allocate space for a string to be inserted.  Probably place that malloc in the setInformations() function.  At the end of main(), those allocated memory areas need to be free'd.

Comment: this line: char *contests_name[]={"cycle_race","swim","running race"}; creates any array of 3 pointers. each pointer to a string. then creates a pointer to that array of 3 pointers  However, referencing the name of an array results in a pointer to that array, so the probably should be:  char contests_name[]={"cycle_race","swim","running race"};

Comment: after this line: printf("Competitor's name: "); the user of your code is going to be expecting the code to supply the competitors name.  Probably the prompt should read: "Please enter the Competitor's name: :

Comment: this line: void setInformations(char *informations[], char *contests_name[]) { contains two parameters, however; the second parameter is not used.  So the compiler should have complained with at warning/error.

Comment: the parameter(s) passed to the setInformations() function are each passing a pointer to an array of pointers.  A much better way to write the prototype and declaration would be:  void setInformations(char **informations, char **contests_name)  then the printf(), scanf(), etc would be written as: printf(... (*informations)[0] );

Answer (score 0):

here : `scanf("%s",*informations[0]);`, you are trying to write in a read-only memory. 
So you have to allocate the memory in the main :

```
int stringSize = 30; // example of length
char* informations[3];
informations[0] = malloc(stringSize);
informations[1] = malloc(stringSize);
informations[2] = malloc(stringSize);

//initialyse the strings to "" : 
informations[0][0] = '\0';
informations[1][0] ='\0';
informations[2][0] ='\0';
```

in setInformations(, you have to delete the * to give scanf the adress of the memory where to write). correct syntax : `scanf("%s",informations[0]);`

Answer (score 0):

Take the * out of the scanf:

```
 scanf ("%s", informations[0]);
```

...and allocate space for the informations array

```
 char* informations[NUMBER_OF_INFORMATIONS][MAX_NAME_LENGTH] = {{'\0'}};
```

so scanf will have room to put in the info.

Comment: Thank You. I changed char *informations[]... to char *informations[4][20]; and added scanf("%s",informations); weird thing is when I try to do informations[0] it prompts me with an error

Comment: What did you do with informations[0], and what error did you get?

I ran it without error.  I did have to change the parameter of the function to char informations[4][20].  You could fix this with casting, I'm sure.